# Comparing two DataFrames and showing the difference is generating an error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm able to find the difference by comparing the two DataFrames and concatenate the differences into a new DataFrame but there is a problem when values are missing in one of the DataFrames an error is generated: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects` I think there is a problem with the header index. If you can help me it will be great.

```
df1 have one missing value at column 1980 

df1
    Country 1980    1981    1982    1983    1984
    Bermuda         0.00687 0.00727 0.00971 0.00752
    Canada  9.6947  9.58952 9.20637 9.18989 9.78546
 Greenland       7  0.00746 0.00722 0.00505 0.00799
    Mexico  3.72819 4.11969 4.33477 4.06414 4.18464



 df2
    Country 1980    1981    1982    1983    1984
    Bermuda 0.77777 0.00687 0.00727 0.00971 0.00752
    Canada  9.6947  9.58952 9.20637 9.18989 9.78546
  Greenland 0.00791 0.00746 0.00722 0.00505 0.00799
    Mexico  3.72819 4.11969 4.33477 4.06414 4.18464


def process_df(df):
    res = df.set_index('Country').stack()
    res.index.rename('Column', level=1, inplace=True)
    return res

df1 = process_df(df1)
df2 = process_df(df2)
mask = (df1 != df2) & ~(df1.isnull() & df2.isnull())
df3 = pd.concat([df1[mask], df2[mask]], axis=1).rename({0:'From', 1:'To'}, axis=1)
print(df3)
```

I want to show the missing values just like blank space, example below:

```
                            From         To
Country       Column                       
Bermuda       1980          0.77777   
Greenland     1980          0.00791       7
```

Remember the code works fine if there is no missing values but I want to be able to handle and missing values. Thank you

Comment: What is that missing value? a `NaN`, an empty string, a whitespace...?

Comment: you should replace the whitespace with `np.nan`

Comment: @HaleemurAli That is still generating error

Comment: @RafaelC Is a white space, if you look at the df1 there is a missing value at column 1980

Comment: Check the `dtypes`.  With missing values, the `dtype` of the `1980` column might be different.

Comment: @hpaulj The data type of the 1980 column is the same